# C++ How can I scan the user's string input for a specific word/words?

Tags: c++

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string sentence;
    cin >> sentence;
    string word = "banana";
    regex r("\\b" + word + "\\b");
    smatch s;
    if (regex_search(sentence, s, r)) {
        cout << "success" << endl;
    }
}
```

I got this to partially work. I type in a sentence that includes the word banana, and here comes the problem. If I type banana as the first word in my sentence it will detect it(example: banana etc), but if it's not the first word (example: etc banana) it will not detect it. Is there a fix for it? and yes, I am using namespace because it makes my life easier.

Comment: Are you sure your reggae is correct?

Comment: Are you aware that for a simple search like this, `std:string::find` is sufficient?

Comment: By the way, `using namespace` is generally accepted bad practice only at global scope in header files.

Comment: @ForceBru That's a lovely typo.

Comment: @ForceBru I'm pretty sure their dread-locks are in the right shape ;-) ...

Comment: @AlanStokes ow, yeah, didn't notice it... Funny :) I think it's just f*cking MacOS spellchecker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"I type in a sentence that includes the word banana, and here comes the problem. If I type banana as the **first word** in my sentence it will detect it(example: banana etc), but if it's not the first word (example: etc banana) it will not detect it."*

The code as you have it

```
std::cin >> sentence;
```

only reads a single word from input (up to the next whitespace delimiter).

> *"Is there a fix for it?"*

Of course: If you want to get a whole sentence from input, you rather use

```
std::getline(std::cin,sentence);
```

---

Also note, using `std::regex()` for such a simple case is much too heavy. If you really only want to look up simple sequences like `"banana"` and not patterns, [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), will serve you well (at much less cost).

---

> *"and yes, I am using namespace because it makes my life easier."*

In the end it won't make your life easier, but just the opposite. You are just prone to make collisions with the `std` namespace in your code (think for example about user defined functions for `min()`, `max()`, `swap()`, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot that cin only takes one word. And if it namespace std won't serve me well in the long run then I will drop this habbit. I am trying to make a simple AI that responds to certain inputs, if regex is "too heavy" is std::string::find the best alternative?